# Is UML class diagram operation not important in ontology?

Tags: owl, ontology, class-diagram

I am developing an algorithm converting UML class diagram into OWL ontology. Based on may reviews, I am unable to find any works that emphasizing on one element of class diagram which is operation. Is operation not really important or can be neglected from ontology modelling?

Comment: to be honest, you're a bit late ... this has already been done by several people ... I know at least two papers + the approach of the TopRaid people.

Comment: and it has even been asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49782706/converting-uml-to-owl-ontology

Comment: Yes, I am aware on that..however based  my review, I didn't see any emphasis on an element of class diagram which is OPERATION e.g. getName():String..so it left me wondering in ontology conversion did OPERATION can be neglected?